# JRebel does not working with Spring-Boot app in Intellij IDEA

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, jrebel

I have set up JRebel in Intellij IDEA for spring-boot project, I have followed all the steps to install it in the correct way, but it is still not working, I have the following pom.xml configuration:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
</dependency>

           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.zeroturnaround</groupId>
                <artifactId>jrebel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <addResourcesDirToRebelXml>true</addResourcesDirToRebelXml>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-rebel-xml</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Box is also checked:

[image]

The funny thing is when I do changes in the source code and then go to the bytecode or .properties I can see the changes that have been made, but nothing is changing on the front-end...
Every time I compile the changed file I can see the following message in the event log:
[image]

From which I can conclude that changes should be applied.
I'm using out of the box servlet container which provides spring-boot, if I'm not wrong it is - Tomcat.
If any one knows, can you help me where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

how do you start your SpringBoot application? With start buttons in IntelliJ or using the command line? I think you can remove the JRebel plugin from Maven pom.xml if you make sure that checking boxes in the JRebel panel generates a file called "rebel.xml". If the rebel.xml pom is generated, just verify it's content if it points to the folder with your compiled classes. After that, run "mvn clean compile package" and rerun your application again. If you start your application using buttons in IntelliJ, use JRebel buttons instead of normal ones. If from the command line, follow instructions in the plugin menu.